# Passing params from links to components - react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am trying build a profile page, where user information gets displayed.

The route is - localhost:3000/profile/, and I want to prevent showing user id's in the url.

Example: instead of localhost:3000/profile/10, I just want to see localhost:3000/profile/.

I currently use the first approach, but my boss asks me to change to the second approach.

Although, getting the id of the current logged in user is pretty easy. My challenge is getting at least id's of listed users passed to the profile component.

I'm using react-router-dom, and redux. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you can remove the user id from the url I am just going to give you the answer how you can pass in the id through the link. Since you are using `react-router-dom`, you can just pass in the user id as:

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/profile',
  state: { id: userId }
}}>
  <button>Profile</button>
</Link>
```

here for the `userId` just pass in the userid that you want to pass to the profile, and later in the profile component you can get this id as `this.props.location.state.id`

Comment: Cool If this is your answer please mark the answer as correct